# How to install Umbraco on VS2015?

Tags: installation, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm following the guide oninstalltion Umbraco [here](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Install/install-umbraco-with-nuget). It seems that they don't mention VS2015but I followed as closely I could by installing it into an empty MVC 5 project.

However, as I install UmbracoCMS via NuGet, I see this error (and a bunch of alikes, all nagging about DNX 5 being not supported).

> NU1002 The dependency Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers 3.2.3 in project PocUmbraco does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
>
> c:\users\chamster\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PocUmbraco\src\PocUmbraco\project.json

I'm very unclear what to do about it. I've googled but didn't find anything helpful, likely due to ignorance and limited experience with Umbraco.

Comment: Can you please verify if your package.json is all correct? Also check for any references to RC versions

Comment: How do I do that? I reviewed *project.json* and found apassage about dnx5. After removing it, leaving only DNX4.5 the errors were gone but I have no idea what I've just done. Also, I can't publish to the Azure now. No errors, just greyed out menu... Do you know of a guide for VS2015 and Umbraco? It's very confusing at the moment, hehe.

Comment: @Ash This line seems to get executed (in Startup.cs) as I can see it when I run the site locally: *context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");*. I was, however, expecting a bit more graphics and stuff out of the box...

Comment: Honestly, I haven't even touched this version as of now. But seems like you are on right track now mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually installed into a ASP.NET 5 project (which has MVC6).
You should not use the ASP.NET 5 template, but something like 4.5.2 or 4.6. DotnetCore is not supported by Umbraco. Not sure about ASP.NET 5, but according to this, it does not sound very supported to me:
https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/66903-umbraco-on-linux-with-aspnet-5

Also, leave out azure if you just want to get a POC running.
Then after you created your empty ASP.NET project, install nuget package UmbracoCms, and hit that F5 button and go from there :-)

Comment: So much for cutting edge, go with the latest... I got it working once I went with 4.5... Me not like.